# Java NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-ws

I can compile the Java Web Service client fine with the following command:

```
javac 
     -classpath lib\spring-ws-2.0.0-M2-all.jar;lib\xml-apis.jar;lib\j2ee.jar;lib\saaj.jar;lib\saaj-impl.jar 
     WebServiceClient.java
```

When I actually run it (java WebServiceClient), it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate
        at WebServiceClient.<init>(WebServiceClient.java:14)
        at WebServiceClient.main(WebServiceClient.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ws.client.core.
WebServiceTemplate
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 2 more
```

Here's the code for WebServiceClient.java:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessageFactory;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.WebServiceMessageSender;

public class WebServiceClient {

    private static final String MESSAGE =
        "<message xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org\">Hello Web Service World</message>";

    private final WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();

    public void setDefaultUri(String defaultUri) {
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
    }

    // send to the configured default URI
    public void simpleSendAndReceive() {
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(MESSAGE));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source, result);
    }

    // send to an explicit URI
    public void customSendAndReceive() {
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(MESSAGE));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult("http://wsdl",
            source, result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebServiceClient ws = new WebServiceClient();
        ws.setDefaultUri("http://wsdl");
        ws.simpleSendAndReceive();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are the libraries in your runtime environment classpath?

Comment: I included all the jar files with the classpath switch on the command line:  
-classpath lib\spring-ws-2.0.0-M2-all.jar;lib\xml-apis.jar;lib\j2ee.jar;lib\saaj.jar;lib\saaj-impl.jar 
Is that wrong?

Comment: Did you add them on both the `javac` and the `java` call?  You only state you set the classpath on the `javac` command in your Q

Comment: As tim says, one thing is to compile and another thing is to run. Try the command in my answer.

Comment: Try to add one of those jars : http://www.findjar.com/class/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html

Comment: Tried a different version of spring-ws from above URL but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
java -classpath lib\spring-ws-2.0.0-M2-all.jar;lib\xml-apis.jar;lib\j2ee.jar;lib\saaj.jar;lib\saaj-impl.jar WebServiceClient
```

I suppose your folder structure is as follows;

```
\WebServiceClient.java
\WebServiceClient.class
\lib\spring-ws-2.0.0-M2-all.jar
\lib\xml-apis.jar
\lib\j2ee.jar
\lib\saaj.jar
\lib\saaj-impl.jar
```

Comment: Gave me this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WebServiceClient...
Could not find the main class: WebServiceClient.  Program will exit.

Comment: do you execute it where WebServiceClient.class is? Is your WebServiceClient inside a package?

Comment: Yes. I ran the command in the same directory where WebServiceClient.java and WebServiceClient.class are.

Comment: and that directory contains a lib directory with the jars, right?

Comment: Correct. The directory I'm running the java command contains WebServiceClient.java, WebServiceClient.class, and a folder called lib which contains all of the jars.

Comment: and if you just run "java WebServiceClient" it says that cannot find the libraries but it finds the main function?!?!!?!!?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty strange. When I just run "java WebServiceClient", I get the original error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/w
s/client/core/WebServiceTemplate

Comment: that's really weird. All you are doing is adding libraries but executing the same class!!

Answer (score 0):

When you passed in that classpath to your `javac` invocation, it was necessary because your classes referenced files that were defined only in those JARs.

The same holds true at runtime as well, your compiled Java bytecode will need to be able to "see" those JARs in order to load the classes and use the Spring functionality.  So you can't merely invoke `java WebServiceClient` and expect it to work.

Instead you'll need to invoke the command that pakore's answer shows, which looks like it should work.  If in doubt, after successfully compiling, press the Up arrow to rebuffer the last command, delete the `c` from `javac` and delete the `.java` from the filename at the end.  (If your shell doesn't support this, copy-and-paste the previous line via e.g. Notepad).

Comment: The only thing I can think of, then, is that you've got some reasonably complex classloading situation going on, such that the classpath you supply on the command line is **not** the effective classpath of the ClassLoader that's failing to find the file.  Just to check - you're writing some kind of web service client, are you sure this error message is being generated on the *client* side?  Or is it being generated on the server and returned to the client?

Comment: I changed the command to this (adding a ;. at the end of the jar class paths):
java -classpath lib\spring-ws-2.0.0-M2-all.jar;lib\xml-apis.jar;lib\j2ee.jar;lib\saaj.jar;lib\saaj-impl.jar;. WebServiceClient

and now its giving me a different error: ServiceClient
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/b
eans/factory/InitializingBean

I think I maybe just need to find the missing JAR.

Comment: Found a couple more jar files I needed and now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate** is located on **spring-ws-core.jar**. Have you checked if its included on your WAR/EAR when the application is deployed to the Application Server where you are attempting to run it in or if its included as part of the server's lib?  A successful compilation doesn´t mean all classes required to run an application will be there at runtime.